# Different scales for 2D plots grouped in 3D perspective in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to realize a plot similar to the one in the following figure:
[image]

I started from the code contained in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099518/plotting-a-series-of-2d-plots-projected-in-3d-in-a-perspectival-way

m3dplot and 3D collections seems to work well, however, I have problem with including axes with different heights in the same plot. In the figure they should be different, but in the example attached and in the documentation I found only plots with only one scale. Is there a way to achieve that using matplotlib?

At the moment this is the rough outcome that I obtained:

[image]

This is a MWE to get an idea:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

x   = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
y1  = np.ones(x.size)
y2  = np.ones(x.size)*2
y3  = np.ones(x.size)*3
z1  = np.sin(x*10)
z2   = 10*np.sin(x*10)
z3   = 100*np.sin(x*10)


pl.figure()
ax = pl.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y1, z1, color='r')
ax.plot(x, y2, z2, color='g')
ax.plot(x, y3, z3, color='b')

ax.add_collection3d(pl.fill_between(x, 0.95*z1, 1.05*z1, color='r', alpha=0.3), zs=1, zdir='y')
ax.add_collection3d(pl.fill_between(x, 0.90*z2, 1.10*z2, color='g', alpha=0.3), zs=2, zdir='y')
ax.add_collection3d(pl.fill_between(x, 0.85*z3, 1.15*z3, color='b', alpha=0.3), zs=3, zdir='y')
```